# SQL XML Data Type with HTML Markup

Tags: sql, xml-parsing

I have a SQL table that has two columns.  One is the identity, the other is a large XML document (originated from InfoPath documents which I imported to SQL).  I have select statements that pull data from different nodes.  A few of the nodes have HTML in them.  When using the select statement to get the node value, it strips all the HTML off of it and just returns the text.  These are RTF fields.  Does anyone know how I can get it returned to keep the markup?

My select statement:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-01-06T15:50:09' AS my
)

SELECT
id,
rec.value('(/my:myFields/my:RoutineCare/my:field2837)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')  AS RoutNotes
FROM
tblXml
WHERE id = 14
GO
```

And what it returns does not contain the HTML that you see below, only the text that is within that markup.

The XML in the SQL table:

```
<my:field2837>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:space="preserve">
    <div>
        <font face="Times New Roman" size="1">
        <font face="Times New Roman" size="1">
        <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin:0in 0in 0pt"><span style="color:#1e3c7b"><font size="1" /></span></p>
        <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin:0in 0in 0pt"><font size="2"><span style="color:#1e3c7b"><font face="Arial">INN:  100%, deductible waived<br /></font></span></font></p>
        <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin:0in 0in 0pt"><font size="3"><font face="Arial"><font size="2" /></font></font> </p>
        <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin:0in 0in 0pt"><font size="3"><font face="Arial"><font size="2">This plan utilizes the Mandated Benefit list - See Health Care Reform - Preventive Care Coverage PPM for age limits and benefits.<br /><br /></font></font></font></p></font>
        </font>
        <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin:0in 0in 0pt"><span style="font-family:&amp;apos;color:red"><font size="3">This plan offers Expanded Women’s Health Services as outlined in UMR’s recommendation chart.  See “Health Care Reform – Women’s Expanded Preventive Health Provision” PPM for specifics and benefits</font></span></p>
        <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin:0in 0in 0pt"><span style="font-family:&amp;apos;color:red"><font size="3" /></span> </p><span style="font-family:&amp;apos;color:red">
        <p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:normal;margin:0in 0in 0pt"><font color="#000000"><font face="Arial"><b><u><span style="background:lime;font-size:10pt">Routine Covered Services</span></u></b><span style="background:lime;font-size:10pt">:<span>  </span>apply In-Network benefits for services rendered by an Out-of-Network provider if services are not available from an In-Network provider within 50 miles from the covered member’s residence. U&amp;C applies</span></font></font></p></span><span style="font-family:&amp;apos;color:#1e3c7b;font-size:10pt" /></div>
    </html>
</my:field2837>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone ever wants to know, I figured it out:

CONVERT(nvarchar(max), t.rtf1.query('/my:myFields/my:Ambulance/my:field2618/child::*')) AS AmbNotes

FROM
    tblXml
CROSS APPLY rec.nodes('/my:myFields/my:Ambulance') AS t(rtf1)
GO